# How to automatically retrieve data when new data detected and show on datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

Currently I have a public retrieve class, and a timer to execute this retrieve class every 3 seconds. But I realized that there is a problem when more and more data comes in. I cannot drag up or down when I'm trying to view each row because every 3 second it continuously retrieve data from table and the datagridview keep repopulate.
(window form)

I got another solution and just wanted to ask expert(s) or guru(s) whether it is workable or not? Or maybe some one can guide me to another solution?

**My second solution:**
1. Retrieve count(*) [current rows in table] and paste it to label.

2. Use data reader to read the count(*) table every 3 seconds, if has row then perform no action, if has row = false then execute retrieve class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984294%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) your data to your visual elements? [Also here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This would be the standard approach for hooking up your UI layer and backend, and is event driven rather than requiring, for example, polling.

Comment: I posted c# examples, but you can usually tab between them and vb ones. Besides, they work the same here.

Comment: hi very thx your help! i try to understand the codes of the second link you posted, just not sure wanted to ask you, if i got 3 window forms application connect to a central database, the codes sample you show me can solve my problem?  [Dim commandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)

        ' Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource. 
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table]

Comment: I don't know, this is just guidance on how to connect your view and your viewmodel.